# Give the path to the inserted USB key to a script

Tags: windows-xp, usb, script, camera, drive-letter

I'd like to run a given Perl script whenever I connect my camera to my PC, so that this script will download all the photos on it.  But as the drive letter for the camera may change depending on what's already connected, I need to pass this drive letter as an argument to the script.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in [your other question](https://superuser.com/questions/16197/any-way-to-ensure-that-a-usb-key-always-has-the-same-drive-letter) for this problem also [USBDLM](http://www.uwe-sieber.de/usbdlm_e.html) could be the solution. E.g. it could start your photo sync tool on connect or any script you like.

You can use the [%DriveLetter%](http://www.uwe-sieber.de/usbdlm432_help_e.html#variables) variable to be passed to your script. Here is an example configuration section:

```
[OnArrival1]
open=your_script.bat %DriveLetter%
```

See the [documentation](http://www.uwe-sieber.de/usbdlm432_help_e.htm) for details (the included Windows documentation is much more readable).

Answer (score 2):

You could:

1. Assign a different drive letter, then it will stay the same. This can be done in `devmgmt.msc`
2. Instead of a drive letter, assign a filesystem path (like in Linux).

   For example, `"C:\Users\Xavier\Desktop\USB key\"` instead of `"E:\"`. Again, `devmgmt.msc`
3. Run `mountvol`, copy the `\\?\Volume{blah-blah}` path, replace the `?` with a period `.` and use *that* path instead.

   For example, `\\?\Volume{e095d6a2-a763-11dd-afc0-806d6172696f}\boot.ini` in my computer is the same as `C:\boot.ini`. (Not sure if this remains static all the time - but it worked for me so far.)

Comment: The '\\?\Volume{blah-blah}' is a nice trick I did not know...  But is it possible to have Windows give it to a script when the drive is inserted?

Comment: I doubt it's possible to automatically run a script _at all_.